# What to use for ^(void)completion token

Tags: iphone, xcode, deprecated, ios

Working on updating an app for iPhones and iPod touches with the latest iOS SDK, I'm trying to fix a few deprecations and I don't know how to finish the string.  It ends with a token reading "^(void)completion", but I don't know what to fill it with.  I've tried looking around for it, but I can't find anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: The SDK you are referring to is still under NDA. I have modified your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a malformed attempt to have a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html). This is presumably a completion handler, which is a C block that takes no parameters and returns nothing.

If you don't need a completion handler, you can just pass `nil`. Otherwise you can pass a block, which would look like

```
[obj someFuncWithCompletion:^{
    // this is the block here, the ^{ code }
}];
```

Comment: Huh, thanks that helps.  I had no idea what to replace it with.